# Apache2 and mod_wsgi: Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process

Tags: apache, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi

My application is running with an Apache 2 server using mod_wsgi, Flask, and Python 2.7. Oddly enough, the application crashes when the page refreshes. For me, this happens exactly on every other refresh. You can see it [here](http://amp.pharm.mssm.edu/g2e/test). Furthermore, in Chrome, if I open the web inspector tool, the program does *not* crash.

In the logs, I see:

```
[Tue Apr 14 13:45:29.137444 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 32713] [client 146.203.54.32:58816] Truncated or oversized response headers received from daemon process 'localhost:80': /etc/g2e/htdocs/g2e
[Tue Apr 14 13:45:29.671493 2015] [core:notice] [pid 28845] AH00052: child pid 640 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Tue Apr 14 13:45:29.671520 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 28845] mod_wsgi (pid=640): Process 'localhost:80' has died, deregister and restart it.
[Tue Apr 14 13:45:29.671524 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 28845] mod_wsgi (pid=640): Process 'localhost:80' terminated by signal 11
[Tue Apr 14 13:45:29.671527 2015] [wsgi:info] [pid 28845] mod_wsgi (pid=640): Process 'localhost:80' has been deregistered and will no longer be monitored.
...
```

FWIW, I am using

```
Linux 3.16.7-7-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec 17 18:00:44 UTC 2014 (762f27a) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Discussion on mod_wsgi mailing list is https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/JdSAnqoJDTw

Comment: I don't think it's fair to answer my question, since I didn't properly fix the issue myself. But FWIW, I was unable to resolve the issue using Graham's suggestions and was worried about fiddling around too much since the server is already in production. I ended up using Docker with a clean install of Apache, mod_wsgi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a tweak. I had this problem but now it's working somehow.

- I tried to run `mod_wsgi` as a daemon. My application didn't work and I had this error message in the logs.
- however running `mod_wsgi` as non-daemon worked, for instance

  ```
  python manage.py runmodwsgi --reload-on-changes # for Django
  ```

  So I once again launched it then killed it.
- my app is still running :)

(mod_wsgi 4.4.[1-13], apache2, python 2.7, Django 1.7, Debian8 fresh install, with or without virtualenv)

Comment: Welp, daemon mode is the recommended config in production at least.